# Informatica Split Multiple Connected Lookups to same field of 1 Target Table

Tags: lookup, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter, lookup-tables

In Informatica mapping, I need to split multiple Connected Lookups with different lookup conditions and connect the output port to the same field of 1 Target Table.

For eg., I have 10 LKPs (all are generating different values for Acc_No based on 10 different scenarios) and I need to connect the output ACC field to the ACC field of the target table. I had created 10 Target tables in the mapping and linked only the output port from each of these 10 LKPs to the target table ACC field. But that is causing 10 times the data to be loaded in the target table. I have 100 records in source and need only 100 in target but its loading 1000.

How can I achieve this - Do I need 10 Target table instance in the mapping or can it be done with 1 but using some other technique to ensure no duplication of LKP matched records?

[My mapping snippet is here - I have 10 such LKPs in the mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIzfc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to understand the insertion process. If you have 10 targets of same table/ flat file, and you populate same column (ACC) using 10 lookups, it will cause the data to be loaded the no of times you use the target which leads to duplicates.

Even if you use 10 different conditions in each lookup, there should be only one output port to populate ACC column.

The correct solution is,

1. Use only one Target
2. Use unconnected lookup, seems to be you are mapping only one column from the lookup 
   (using connected lookup will cause performance issue)
3. Use expression transformation before the target and organize the result and pass it to the target port.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand completely but i am trying to answer.
A. You need an expression transformation after all lookups which covers all your scenarios.
B. You need to have only one single target after expression above. Please remove all other targets.

More details, In expression you need to write a big IF-ELSE condition using `IIF()` based on your different scenarios. For example, it could be -
`IIF( lkp1_val ='India' AND Acc_Type='Receivables', lkp1_val_Acc_no , 
IIF (lkp2_val ='Austria' AND Acc_Type='Receivables', lkp2_val_Acc_no ,...
))`

My point #A is solving your issue and point #B is showing why you are seeing 1000 rows in target with your mapping.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked as per your suggestion - after connecting my unconnected lookups to an EXP before the target and merging the values into 1 port via a big IIF condition ;..